# Python try except not expected when using with open

Tags: python

Recently I've been practicing lessions by Jason Cannon on O'reilly: https://learning.oreilly.com/videos/python-for-beginners/9781789617122/9781789617122-video10_3/

At 6:55 of the 'Files, Part II' section, I have a problem practicing error catch following the idea in the video. My code:

```
with open('data.txt') as file:
    try:
        file_content = file.read()
    except:
        file_content = ''
print(len(file_content))
```

The idea is to catch error when the file is not found, the try block runs but the except block not. I expected the file_content has length of 0 instead of error shows up. Please tell me where I did wrong. Thank you very much

Comment: What's the output?

Comment: The error is generated in the first line of your code, before the try statement.  You may want to move it inside, and the consider how you might handle it.

Comment: I got it! Thank you but then I have to write 'with open' twice?

Comment: @Samwise: the output says file not found

Comment: Does it give a line number that raised the exception?  (Was it inside your `try` block or was it... earlier?)

Comment: @Samwise: 'IOError: Could not find file'. I just corrected it, the code runs now, thank you!

Comment: The important piece of information here is that it should also include a line number, which I'm guessing would point you at the `open()` as the source of the error rather than the `read()` (which in turn would tell you that your program never got to its `try` block!)

Comment: @Samwise: Sorry for I didn't get 'line number' that you mentioned but now I do! Yes, the line number is 1, thank you for pointing it out so that I can understand it clearly!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the file isn't found, it's `open` that raises the error, not the attempt to read from it.

```
try:
    with open('data.txt') as file:
        file_content = file.read()
except (FileNotFoundError, IOError):
    file_content = ''
```

Note that if `open` raises a `FileNotFound` error, then no context manager will actually be created, and so there is no need for the `with` statement to try to execute an `__exit__` method before control passes to the exception handler.